# I cannot run miniedit on my ubuntu console. It sends this error message

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./miniedit.py", line 63, in <module>
    from mininet.net import info,debug, warn, setLogLevel
ImportError: No module named mininet.net
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Reviewers: How can you be so sure that this question is unclear when you have never used this app which is in the default Ubuntu repositories? Trust me, this question is not unclear.

Answer (score 1):

MiniEdit is Mininet's graphical user interface. It is provided by the *mininet* package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu 22.04 and later mininet depends on the default installed version of python3.

1. Install mininet from the default Ubuntu repositories.

   ```
   sudo apt install mininet
   ```
2. Change directories to the directory containing miniedit.py.

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mininet/examples/
   ```
3. To run MiniEdit, execute this command:

   ```
   python3 miniedit.py
   ```

In Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier run the following commands to install mininet.

1. Install mininet from the default Ubuntu repositories.

   ```
   sudo apt install python2.7 mininet
   ```
2. Change directories to the directory containing miniedit.py.

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet/examples/
   ```
3. To run MiniEdit, execute this command:

   ```
   python miniedit.py
   ```

   The online MiniEdit instructions say that you need `sudo` to start MiniEdit, but whoever wrote those instructions was wrong. In Ubuntu you don't need to be root to start MiniEdit with the python interpreter. It's a bad idea to start graphical applications as root in Ubuntu. You can avoid the unnecessary use of `sudo` by starting MiniEdit as an ordinary user.

MiniEdit has a simple user interface that presents a canvas with a row of tool icons on the left side of the window, and a menu bar along the top of the window. Create a custom network topology using MiniEdit by dragging objects from the left panel onto the canvas.

[image: MiniEdit]

MiniEdit doesn't have any built-in grid lines to align the objects, and when you click an object to connect it to another object, it sometimes moves a bit on the canvas out of correctly matched alignment. To improve the alignment of the network diagram you can install a screen ruler app with the following command.

```
sudo apt install screenruler
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517716/how-to-use-miniedit-in-mininet-can-anyone-suggest-the-commands notes you must launch miniedit.py from a remote terminal "that has visualization" using ssh .